# Como formatar dados numéricos extraídos do banco de dados para valores monetários?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, maskmoney

Estou usando a biblioteca **jquery.maskMoney.js** para formatar os dados monetários do sistema. Mas quando os dados são salvos no banco de dados e retornados para a tela do sistema a formatação é perdida. Como solucionar este problema? Gostaria que a formatação permanecesse, segue algumas telas do sistema que exemplificam este problema.

**1. Dados com formatação monetária: inserindo os dados no formulários**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2. Dados sem formatação monetária: dados sendo carregados a partir do banco de dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

 
**3. Trecho do código da página edita.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-5 form-group">
<label class="control-label">Valor Solicitado (R$)</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="vlSolicitado" name="vlSolicitado" value="{{str_replace('.',',',$projeto->valor_solicitado)}}" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ " maxlength="18"  required>  
</div>
```

**4. Resultado da Consulta do Banco de Dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tem uma função em php: number_format($campo['valorprod'], 2, ',', ''), onde vai a variável que deseja formatar, o número de casas depois da vírgula, o elemento de separação ("," ou ".") e a separação de milhares "" > 1000,00 (sem espaço) ou " " > 1 000,00 (com espaço)

Comment: voce pode salvar de uma forma, apenas usando numeros e depois quando mostra tratar o valor para que seja mostrado como voce deseja.

Comment: Para resolver o problema, aplique a máscara no retorno dos dados após modificar e salvar.

Answer (score 3):

Vou lhe orientar a tratar os dados antes de inseri-los no banco de dados.

1. Suponho que você esteja utilizando **PHP** para tratar as informações antes de inseri-las no banco de dados (**MySQL**).
2. Também parto do princípio que seu banco de dados está devidamente estruturado para receber as informações dos seus formulários.

Para valores monetários o campo deve ser do tipo **DECIMAL(7,2)**, dois dígitos após o ponto e acredito que 7 dígitos antes do ponto lhe é suficiente.

Como você está formatando o valor com uma máscara Jquery, assim que você passa o valor para o PHP, eles também vem formatados.
Exemplo: 2.000,00.

Você precisa eliminar está formatação, pois o seu banco de dados não vai aceitar os caracteres: "." e "," dessa forma gerando um erro.

Se os valores do formulário estão sendo enviados via **POST**, faça assim:

```
// Valor recebido do formulário, campo valor solicitado (2.000,00)
$valor = $_POST['valorSolicitado'];

// Removo da variável o "."
$valor = str_replace('.' '', $valor);
// Substituo a "," pelo "." pois é esse formato que o campo do seu banco de dados vai aceitar
$valor = str_replace(',' '.', $valor);

// Esta variável irá imprimir:
// 2000.00
```

Quando você recuperar o valor do seu bando de dados, formate-o usando uma função do PHP chamada **number_format**:

```
// Valor recuperado do banco de dados (2000.00)
$valor = $valor_do_banco_de_dados;

$valor = number_format($valor, 2, ',', '.');

// Esta variável irá imprimir:
// 2.000,00
```

Comment: Parabéns pela resposta, eu usei a função "number_format" neste caso. Mas, o erro permanece pois a função não está colocando os pontos de milhar. E o resultado foi: R$ 2000,00 ao invés de 2.000,00.

Comment: Me perdoe, não coloquei o "." na função, pois esperava que a máscara Jquery fizesse isso pra você. Alterei a função colocando o ".".

Ficando assim:

$valor = number_format($valor, 2, ',', '.');

Espero que possa ser útil.

Comment: Alburqueque, Muito obrigada, o erro foi corrigido.

Answer (score 0):

Olá @Ruama, experimenta fazer um explode com php no valor obtido pelo select do bd, antes de exibi-lo no form. Por exemplo:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE id=$id_escolhido";
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
   $valor = $row['valor'];
   $valor_explode = explode(",", $valor);
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta.

Comment: Oi @Ruama funcionou em sua aplicação?

Comment: não funcionou eu testei com a função "number_format" , mas o erro permanece pois a função não está colocando os pontos de milhar.

Comment: quando vc obtém do bd, vem nesse formato "2000,00" isso? então vc poderia remover essa virgula com o explode, transformado o valor assim "200000". Dessa forma quando vc colocar no input, configurado com o jquery maskMoney, irá ficar no formato ideal, "2.000,00"

Comment: segue a solução:                           <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="vlSolicitado" name="vlSolicitado" value="{{number_format($projeto->valor_solicitado, 2, ',', '.')}}" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ "  maxlength="18"  required>